# regex expression to find nº X

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am using the following expression to find 'nº' followed by a number (e.g. 'bla bla nº 5' should return groups 'nº' and '5'):

```
(\bnº\b)\s+(\d+)
```

doesn't seem to work. Anybody know why?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe because you do not use `@` before the regex declaration?

Comment: @ChristophKn But that matches other text, and doesn't separate out the number.

Comment: Guys, [`º` is a letter (*Lo - Letter, other*)](http://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C2%BA#title) :) Nice. So, the regex should work if you declare it with a verbatim string literal.

Comment: Don't know which original question could be used to close this one as a dupe.

Comment: I am using  @"(\bnº\b)\s*(\d+)" in c#; just didn't copy the @ because it is not needed in the regex101 tester. so that's not it unfortunately! 'nº' is literal string. in the regex101 tester it doesn't work ...

Comment: The only problem was that you tested the regex at a wrong online tester. The question must be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Remove the second \b

```
(\bnº)\s+(\d+)
```

\b matches a word boundry between a character matched by \w and a character not matched by \w

\w  matches characters a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _. You are using º, which is not included

Comment: No need removing second `\b` because [`º` is a letter (Lo - Letter, other)](http://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%C2%BA#title). In .NET, `\b` is Unicode aware, it is not JavaScript or any other language where you need to specifically indicate that your pattern should be Unicode aware.

Comment: Why is the answer accepted? It is wrong from all aspects. See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cbn%c2%ba%5cb)%5cs%2b(%5cd%2b)&i=bla+bla+n%c2%ba+5) where what you say should not work works. `(\bnº\b)\s+(\d+)` works correctly. OP regex was right from the very beginning. Surely, the second `\b` is redundant, but there is no error.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your regex as a verbatim string literal, it will work.

```
var pattern = @"(\bnº\b)\s+(\d+)";
              ^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/4jfKsT):

```
var pattern = @"(\bnº\b)\s+(\d+)";
var line = "bla bla nº 5";
var result = Regex.Matches(line, pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(p=>string.Format("{0}-{1}", p.Groups[1].Value,p.Groups[2].Value)).ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```